# What does the "-?" syntax mean in TypeScript mapped types?

Tags: typescript

Can anybody please explain what that "-?" in the following TypeScript type declarations
means, compared to just using a "?" there?

```
type ValidationMap<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: Validator<T[K]> }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a wildcard.  The `-?` notation was added in TypeScript 2.8 as a way of [removing the optional modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#improved-control-over-mapped-type-modifiers) from mapped types.

Basically, it means that `ValidationMap<T>` has the same keys as `T`, but none of the properties of `ValidationMap<T>` is optional, even if the corresponding property of `T` is.  For example:

```
type Example = ValidationMap<{a: string, b?: number | undefined}>;
// type Example = {a: Validator<string>, b: Validator<number | undefined>}
```

Here, `Example` has a required `b` property even though the type it's mapped from has an optional `b` property.

(Note that if you change `-?` to just `?` or to `+?`, it becomes the opposite... you would be *adding* the optional modifier.  The `?` notation was added in TypeScript 2.1 as part of the [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#mapped-types) feature, while the `+?` notation was introduced in TypeScript 2.8 along with `-?`.)

Hope that helps.  Good luck!